# Javascript program cannot get values from input fields, and if statement returns weird results

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a short script to calculate how many years should a sum of money (the principal) stay in an account at a certain interest rate to return a desired sum, with taxes being subtracted from the annual gains at the end of each year. The sum is then entirely reinvested at the same interest rate, until it reaches or exceeds the desired sum. The script should return the number of years required to reach the desired sum.

If the principal is already equal or superior to the desired sum, it should return "0" (since no investment is required).

The function itself works well (the math part is **not** the issue), but when I try to set up input fields so that the amounts can be entered manually, nothing works and my browser crashes...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Principal: <input type="number" id="pri" value="1000"><br>
Interest: <input type="number" id="int" value="0.05"><br>
Tax: <input type="number" id="tax" value="0.18"><br>
Desired: <input type="number" id="des" value="1100"><br>

<button onclick= "calculateYears()">Return Years</button>

<p id= "test"></p>

<script>
function calculateYears(principal, interest, tax, desired) {
   var years = 0;
   principal = document.getElementById("pri").value;
   interest = document.getElementById("int").value;
   tax = document.getElementById("tax").value;
   desired = document.getElementById("des").value;
    
   if (principal < desired) {
       do {
           var first = principal * interest;
           var second = principal * interest * tax;
           var net = first - second;
           principal += net;
           years ++;
       }
       while (principal < desired);
       document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += years + "<br>";
   } else { 
       document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += years + "<br>";       
   }    
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried setting each value to "" (empty field) and enter them manually, replacing variables name, changing the structure, using other types of loop, simplifying the code and analyzing it to understand what doesn't work. I got down to this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Principal: <input type="number" id="pri" value="999"><br>
Desired: <input type="number" id="des" value="1100"><br>

<button onclick= "calculateYears()">Return Years</button>

<p id= "test"></p>

<script>
function calculateYears(numberOne, numberTwo) {
    numberOne = document.getElementById("pri").value;
    numberTwo = document.getElementById("des").value;
    
    if (numberOne < numberTwo) {
     document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = numberOne;
    } else { 
     document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = numberTwo;  
    }    
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code somehow works (it doesn't crash and returns something), but not correctly for every case. For example, when numberOne is set to "999" and numberTwo to "1100", it returns "1100" although it should return "999" (since numberOne < numberTwo, and thus ("test").innerHTML = numberOne).

I don't understand what's going on, nor what resources I could use to help myself more. Could please you tell me that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just a tip for clarity: remove the arguments from your function -- you're not passing anything in. Alternatively: actually pass the values in as parameters rather than pulling them off the dom inside your function.

Comment: "remove the arguments from your function"
How could I rewrite the code to pass arguments? I still don't fully get the flow of how it works.
"pass the values in as parameters"
Could you give me an example?

Comment: your html code dosen't close the tags properly, a good code always keep the troubleshooting simpler, please close inputs with /> and br. I always include name too, but it is optional I think.
Another point: What browser(JS engine) and version you are using?

Comment: @Octavio If you wrap the inputs in a form tag with a name or id attribute: `<form name="myForm">`  and `</form>`,  then you can reference those inputs in your function call in the HTML like this: `onclick= "calculateYears(myForm.pri.value, myForm.des.value)"`. So you don't need to find them with getElementById. You'll still need to parse the strings, but that's better done inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values are all strings and need to be numbers to get everything to work right.

Instead of:

```
numberOne = document.getElementById("pri").value;
```

You need something like this:

```
numberOne = parseFloat(document.getElementById("pri").value);
```

This will convert the string into a floating-point number and all of your math should work correctly.

Comment: Awesome! It works!

Is adding "parseFloat()" the only way to pass numeral values? I thought that adding type="number" in the HTML would allow the program to recognize numeric values, do you know why it wasn't enough?

Comment: `parseFloat(src:string)` and `parseInt(src:string, radix:int)` are normal ways to convert a string into a number. But you can also use `Number(src)`. `type="number"` only limits what can be entered by the user but the `.value` is still a string.